# Google Sheets Put "PASS" in one cell if another cell is green / "FAIL" if red

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google Sheet 1 with a result in a cell that will turn green or red based on conditional statements that evaluate if the result is good or bad. On sheet 2 I would like to have post PASS or FAIL based on the color of the cell in sheet 1. Any help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHEpsZrxRj0Z-xefTjkjnr7gH9AgAp8me1li3SXbB4Q/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

not like you imagine but it can be done:

[image]

check this demo sheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fui6GfRvgqYgg4CoLuGchXew7ahMCNg-jlt-yb7RVfY/edit#gid=0)**